# Identifying a set having a chair with a brown seat and circular base with surrounding gray pieces

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I bought a bunch of partial assemblies and bulk pieces. I want to identify what set this belongs to.

[image: a chair with a brown seat, gray circular base, and surrounding gray pieces]

I suspect it's a *Star Wars* set, but there were no minifigs nor decals to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
Your initial suspicion that this set was from *Star Wars* is...

"***Most impressive.***"

Good job!

[image]

*[Set #75077-1 Homing Spider Droid.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75077-1)*

Comment: To make this answer a teachable moment for the OP, could you add to your answer how you determined this was the correct set, i.e. which pieces made you confident that it was indeed set 75077? Thanks!